# Why does CI create a new row instead of updating?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I'm creating a UI in my application which will allow the user to decide the state of received content, this includes updating it. How does CI handle this?

I've tried the different update methods provided in the query builder part of the documentation, including `replace` and `update`, I pass on the data from the view to the controller, to the model in the form of an array. Yet still, when I try it, it creates a new row with that single value and with all other columns empty.

> view.php

```
<form action="Application/Update" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="mar-id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="mar-read" value="New-value">
<?php echo anchor('http://localhost/dir/dir/dir/index.php/Application/Update', 'update'); ?>
</form>
```

> controller.php

```
public function Update() {

  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->model('Main');

  $id = $this->input->post('mar-id');
  $value = $this->input->post('mar-read');

  $mar = $this->Main->Update($id, $value);

  if ($mar == TRUE) {
    redirect('http://localhost/dir/dir/dir/index.php/Application/Otherpage', 'refresh');
  }
  else {
    redirect('http://localhost/dir/dir/dir/index.php/Application/Otherpage');
  }
}
```

> model.php

```
public function Update($id, $value) {

  $data = array(
    'status' => $value
  );
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $update = $this->db->update('table', $data);

}
```

As I said, I expect the row to be updated based on the row-id provided. Instead it creates a completely new row with that single value. It doesn't return any error messages though.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. query builder is just a helper, it doesn't change the way sql works. if the id doesn't exist for the update it just wont update, it wont somehow insert a new row...

Comment: I know, I meant the documentation, I took it from there

Comment: irregardless, neither the documentation or sql will allow a new row to be created via an update statement.

Comment: True I guess, I noticed I used the get method in my form, changed it, now it doesn't insert a new one but instead does nothing.

Comment: nothing meaning what? blank page? error? refreshes? redirects?

Comment: redirect without refresh, so the else statement in my controller. My bad that isn't nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194965/discussion-between-frogman578-and-alex).

Comment: So the code you have provided is exactly the code you are using???

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes

Comment: Is your controller called Application?

Comment: No it's called something else that I don't want to reveal, anyway how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: But I use the controller name in form action

Comment: So it's not the code you are actually using... No probs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194993/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-frogman578).

Comment: Yes it is but I just used a different name for it, irrelevant

Comment: everything is relevant when your claim is that updates are inserting. obviously something fishy is going on that we are not privy to. form submission in codeigniter is usually quite straightforward. you have some inputs, post to a controller which does some form validation, then post vars are sent to a model where it gets updated or inserted. the entire flow is well documented in the docs, and in tutorials online.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean 'fishy'?

Comment: in my experience on stack, when someone claims x is happening and it is not possible it is because we are seeing a variant or a different aspect of their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes here.

SO to date we have established that performing var_dumps in the controller results in NULL for all your "POST" values.

I've assumed the following for simplicity.

**Controller Name is: Program.php** (Application is NOT an Allowed controller name as it's a foldername)

**Model Name is: Mdl_update.php**

**View is: update_view.php**

**Issue #1:**
Your Form has an issue where you are using an anchor tag which is just a link. It does nothing in submitting any data from the form.

So we have to remove the Anchor Tag and replace it with a Form Submit. You have to Submit the form to get any chance of sending the form data.

For testing your GET and POST I've added in Two different Forms.
**In update_view.php**

```
<!-- Set the Method to GET -->
<form action="program/update" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="mar-id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="mar-read" value="New-value">
    <input type = "submit" name="update" value="Update with GET">
</form>

<!-- Set the Method to POST as this is what the Controller is Expecting -->
<form action="program/update" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="mar-id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="mar-read" value="New-value">
    <input type = "submit" name="update" value="Update with POST">
</form>
```

What I used to display the Form in the controller by simply calling the program/index in the Program controller.

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['row'] = array('id' => 2);
    $data = $this->load->view('update_view', $data, TRUE);
    echo $data;
}
```

So your Controller is looking for POST and not GET. This can be proven by changing the controller up a bit for debugging.

```
public function update() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('mdl_update');

    $id = $this->input->post('mar-id');
    $value = $this->input->post('mar-read');

    echo '<h2>POST Values</h2>';
    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($value);

    // ****************************
    // These are added in for debugging/Demonstration to show values for the form using the GET method.
    $id_get = $this->input->get('mar-id');
    $value_get = $this->input->get('mar-read');

    echo '<h2>GET Values</h2>';
    var_dump($id_get);
    var_dump($value_get);
    // ****************************

    exit('Stopped for Debugging: Method '. __METHOD__.' at Line: '.__LINE__); // Added for Debug

    $mar = $this->mdl_update->Update($id, $value);

    if ($mar == TRUE) {
        redirect(base_url('program/otherpage'), 'refresh');
    } else {
        redirect(base_url('program/otherpage'));
    }
}
```

So you are looking for POST Data when your form method is set to GET. Please be aware of what you are setting. They must match.

If you want to use GET, you need to use `$this->input->get()`
The code above will let you test both.

So you now have a POST and GET Form and the controller is setup to demonstrate the two different types. Choose Either GET or POST!. That is up to you on which one you choose.

**Issue #2: Expecting a return value from your Model when you are not returning anything.**

In your Controller you have the line...

```
$mar = $this->mdl_update->Update($id, $value);
```

And in your Model you have...

```
public function update ($id,$value) {
    $data = array(
        'status' => $value
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('db_table', $data);
}
```

Your Model Method is not returning anything.
You should always look up what your return values are. I am expecting that your intention was to return the value of the update. Looking through the CI Code itself it appears that if things go wrong it will return FALSE (if the database debug is disabled - learnt something new)

I've added in some debug to assist in viewing what is going on here.

```
public function update($id, $value) {
    $data = array(
        'status' => $value
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $update_result = $this->db->update('db_table', $data);

    echo $this->db->last_query(); // Added for DEBUG

    return $update_result;
}
```

Now I cannot get your code to create new rows as you claim. ***It's impossible, with this code, to add new rows.*** So thats happening from something you haven't shown us but that is an aside and not important here.

If we alter the controller to view the model etc (I am only showing the changes ) we would change

```
exit('Stopped for Debugging: Method '. __METHOD__.' at Line: '.__LINE__);

$mar = $this->mdl_update->Update($id, $value);
```

To this

```
$mar = $this->mdl_update->Update($id, $value);
var_dump($mar);
exit('Stopped for Debugging: Method '. __METHOD__.' at Line: '.__LINE__);
```

If you run this and submit either the GET ( Results are NULL ) or POST, the update will always return TRUE. So your redirect etc needs to be looked at on how you decide on one or the other.

I think you should set your table columns to not allow them to be NULL AND add in some "Validation" in your controller.

**ISSUE 3: No Form Validation**
CodeIgniter has a Form Validation Class that I suggest you read. This is getting way too long to go into that here...

So as you go through this, you can add/remove debugging to test what is going on and progress it along the way as I have hopefully shown.

if anything is unclear, just ask. I'm sure I may have left something out.

Comment: through answer. fyi "if things go wrong it will return FALSE (if the database debug is disabled - learnt something new)" it will also return FALSE in the event the query failed. when db_debug is off this is a good way of letting the user know the query failed. if it is on, the app will throw that error and it will look ugly. so if you handle the return of it properly, you can make a nice error message.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thanks, now it recognizes the input values